# Accessing parent route model in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to write a route that need access to its parent's model. I use `this.modelFor()`, but when I do that, the parent's model isn't completely loaded, so all its properties contains `null`.

This is the router, with two dynamic segments:

```js
MGames.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('games', function () {
        this.resource ('game', {path: '/:game_id'}, function () {
            this.resource('board', {path: '/boards/:board_id'});
        });
    });
});
```

This is my GameRoute, who works perfectly:

```js
MGames.GameRoute = Ember.Route.extend ({
    model: function (params) {
        return MGames.Game.find(params.game_id);
    }
});
```

And finally this is the child route, who need access to the Game model, and this is what I wrote. But no matters what I do, the `console.log()` always prints `null`. If I check the `game` variable, the `isLoad` property is always null:

```js
MGames.BoardRoute = Ember.Route.extend ({
    model: function (params) {
        var game = this.modelFor ('game');
        console.log (game.get("id"));
        return MGames.Board.find(game.get("id"), params.board_id);
    }
});
```

Am I doing something wrong, or (as I suspect) I'm missing some Ember concept?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This part of your code looks good. Your assumptions are correct in that, the nested route should get the model of the parent via `modelFor`.

I suspect your find method is the source of the bug. I looked at your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466355/loading-a-single-model-with-ember-js), and I'm assuming the same `Game.find` is used here(?)

The problem is to do with `Promises`. Ember's router understands the async nature of the `model` hook. But it relies on you returning a `Promise` to do it's work. Currently you are using the jQuery promise but returning the `game` object immediately in it's uninitialized state. The query loads from the server but the `model()` hook is assumed to have resolved before that happens.

You want to directly return the jQuery `Promise` from your `model` hook + Do the parsing in the first `then` and return that as the result.

Here's your modified `Game.find`. Same principles apply to the other finders.

```
find: function (game, board) {
  url = [MGames.GAMES_API_URL];
  url.push ('games');
  url.push (game);
  url.push ('boards');
  url.push (board);
  url = url.join('/');

  return $.getJSON(url)
    .then(function(response) {
      var game = MGames.Game.create({isLoaded: false});
      game.setProperties(response);
      game.set('isLoaded', true);

      return game;
    });
}
```

Note that, the game object is returned as is. Ember understands that when the promise is resolved(by returning anything other than a promise), that result is the model for the `model()` hook. This `game` object is the model that will be now be available in `modelFor` in the nested route.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. The funny part is that I tried your modification yesterday, but, god knows why, I only changed the Board `find` method and left the Game one untouched and wrong. Clever me.

By the way, I'd give you another +1 if I could for taking the trouble  to look my previous question and using it to complete the answer. Thank you so much!